# Trouble populating list in view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

Here is the scenario: I am programming a MVC web app to track inventory for the company I work for.  All the data is accessed via an external API. I start by instantiating a Connection object from a class, API_Config.cs, located in the App_Start folder.

```
    using Moraware.JobTrackerAPI4;
    namespace MVCWebgridExample.App_Start
    {
    public class API_Config
    {
        public static void ConnectToAPI()
        {
            //set up connection to API
            var db = new Connection("https://databasename.somecompany.net/databasename/api.aspx", "Username", "Password");
            db.Connect();
        }
    }
```

My Models for Inventory:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Moraware.JobTrackerAPI4;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCWebgridExample.Models
{

    public class InventoryViewModel
    {
        public List<string> locationList { get; set; }
        public string stringLocation { get; set; }
        bool LocationExists { get; set; }
        public List<SerialNumber> SerialList { get; set; }
        public string SerialName { get; set; }
        //strings for button labels in initial prompt
        public string lblScanIn { get; set; }
        public string lblScanOut { get; set; }
    }
    public class ScanViewModel
    {
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public List<InventoryLocation> LocationListFull { get; set; }
        public List<SerialNumber> SerialsInLocation { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> SelectedSerial { get; set; }
        public bool LocationExists { get; set; }


        public static ScanViewModel ScanIn()
        {
            var db = new Connection("https://evolvegranite.moraware.net/evolvegranite/api.aspx", "Craig", "December12012");
            db.Connect();
            var svm = new ScanViewModel
            {
                LocationListFull =db.GetInventoryLocations(),
                SerialsInLocation = db.GetSerialNumbers(new SerialNumberFilter(), new PagingOptions(0, 999, true)),
            };
            return svm;
        }
    }
```

And my view:

```
    @model MVCWebgridExample.Models.ScanViewModel
    @using Moraware.JobTrackerAPI4
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "ScanIn";
    }

    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "frmSerialsFromLocation", id = "frmSerialsFromLocation" }))
    {
        //@Html.ValidationSummary() Add this later by providing metadata to a strongly-typed viewmodel
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Scan an Inventory Location</legend>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="tbLocation" autofocus />
            </div>
            <div>

                <ul>
                    @if (ViewBag.serials != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var s in Model.SerialsInLocation)
                    {
                            <li>@s</li>}
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Scan!" />
    }

</div>
```

Controller:

```
    using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Moraware.JobTrackerAPI4;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MVCWebgridExample.Models;
using System.Text;

namespace MVCWebgridExample.Controllers
{

    public class InventoryController : Controller
    {
        //set up connection to API
        Connection db = new Connection("https://evolvegranite.moraware.net/evolvegranite/api.aspx", "Craig", "December12012");

        // Registering mapping
        //public void RegisterMapping()
        //{
        //    // Signature is the same for both type of objects
        //    Mapper.Register<Connection,mappedConnection>();
        //}

        // GET: Inventory

        public ActionResult Index()

        {
            db.Connect();
            return View();
        }

        // GET: /Inventory/ScanIn
        //[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ScanIn(string stringlocation)
        {
            //var ScanIn = new ScanViewModel(); //create new instance of viewmodel

            //var listSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            db.Connect();

            if (stringlocation != null) //if a location has been scanned
            {
                var locationname = stringlocation; //set the location to a string
                var locationList = db.GetInventoryLocations(); //get a list of ALL locations
                var locationExists = locationList.Exists(x => x.InventoryLocationName == locationname);
                if (locationExists)
                {   //get full list of serials
                    var seriallist = db.GetSerialNumbers(new SerialNumberFilter(), new PagingOptions(0, 999, true));
                    var serialsinlocation = GetSerialsFromLocation(locationname); //get serials from location
                    List<SerialNumber> SerialsInLocation = new List<SerialNumber>(serialsinlocation);

                    foreach (var item in SerialsInLocation)
                    {
                        db.UpdateSerialNumber(item);

                    }
                    ViewBag.serials = SerialsInLocation;
                    return View(SerialsInLocation);
                }
                else return View(); //invalid location
            }
            else return View(); //do nothing because a location has not been scanned
        }

        // POST: /Inventory/ScanIn
        //[HttpPost]
        //public ActionResult ScanIn(string stringlocation)//receives the posted information by form
        //{
        //    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //    {
        //        if (stringlocation != null)
        //        {

        //            db.Connect();
        //            var locationname = stringlocation;
        //            var locationList = db.GetInventoryLocations();
        //            var locationExists = locationList.Exists(x => x.InventoryLocationName == locationname);
        //            var seriallist = db.GetSerialNumbers(new SerialNumberFilter(), new PagingOptions(0, 999, true));
        //            var serialsfromlocation = GetSerialsFromLocation(locationname);
        //            foreach (var item in serialsfromlocation)
        //            {
        //                db.UpdateSerialNumber(item);
        //            }
        //            return RedirectToAction(@"ScanIn");
        //        }
        //        else
        //            return View();
        //    }
        //    else
        //        return View();
        //}

        [HttpGet]
        // GET: /Inventory/ScanOut
        public ActionResult ScanOut()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        //POST: /Inventory/ScanOut
        public ActionResult ScanOut(string stringserial)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //METHODS:
        //query for serials in location 
        public IEnumerable<SerialNumber> GetSerialsFromLocation(string stringLocation)
        {
            //to get the serials we need the location and a list of serials
            //then we can iterate through the list and get only serials
            //in the given location
            var serialnumbers = db.GetSerialNumbers(new SerialNumberFilter(), new PagingOptions(0, 999, true));
            var foundSerial = serialnumbers.Find(x => x.InventoryLocationName.Equals(stringLocation));
            //query for serials in given location
            var serialsinlocation =
                    from s in serialnumbers
                    where s.InventoryLocationName == stringLocation
                    select s;
            return serialsinlocation;
            //ViewBag.SerialsInLocation = serialsinlocation.ToString();
        }

        public static object MapObjects(object source, object target)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProp in source.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var targetProp = target.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == sourceProp.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (targetProp != null && targetProp.GetType().Name == sourceProp.GetType().Name)
                {
                    targetProp.SetValue(target, sourceProp.GetValue(source));
                }
            }
            return target;
        }
    }
    public class MappedEntity
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting your exception? Also, can you show your action method?

Comment: Because `Model` or `Model.SerialsInLocation` is `null`

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I added my controller in the edit. No longer getting a null object reference. Sure could use some help on general site design though. Thanks